# How do i solve this question related to string_Concatenation using C?

Tags: c, string-concatenation

I am new to coding. This is a Question from the #30 days code on Hackerrank.
But, I'm unable to solve it. can anyone help me by telling me what's the problem here?

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <math.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main() {
    int i = 4;
    double d = 4.0;
    char s[] = "Hello ";
    // Declare second integer, double, and String variables.
    int j;
    char *ptr=s;
    double c;
    char p[100];
    // Read and save an integer, double, and String to your variables.
    scanf("%d",&j);
    scanf("%lf",&c);
    scanf("%[^\n]%*c",p);
    // Print the sum of both integer variables on a new line.
    printf("%d\n",i+j);
    printf("%.1lf\n",c+d);
    printf("%s%s",s,p);
    // Print the sum of the double variables on a new line.
    
    // Concatenate and print the String variables on a new line
    // The 's' variable above should be printed first
    return 0;
}
```

It is showing the result

```
Input:
12
4
Output:
16
8.0
Hello o}┌vl
╤
```

As you can see I want to print concatenated string but it wouldn't even allow me to input the data into the string.

Comment: Aniket Mani, Curious, why code `scanf()` with a `"%*c"` after `"%[^\n]"`, but not a `"%*c"` after `"%lf"`?

Comment: @chux-ReinstateMonica Isn't `"%*c"` for characters, but `"%lf"` is a floating-point type data type. If I'm wrong, then I'm curious.

Comment: Dodged answering with a question - hmmm.  `"%*c"` is for reading 1 character and not saving it.  Why code that after `"%[^\n]"`?

Comment: @chux-ReinstateMonica I only added `"%*c"`, because the program was going to be checked by hackerrank, I didn't know how they would give inputs.

Comment: @chux-ReinstateMonica You see I'm new , I don't even understand concepts like `buffer`,

Comment: _buffer_ has nothing to do with the problem.  Code here lacks simple checks of the return values of `scanf()` which would have quickly informed that `scanf("%[^\n]%*c",p);` failed.  Tip: always check the return value of input functions.  `scanf("%[^\n]%*c",p);` --> `if (scanf("%[^\n]%*c",p) != 1) puts("Fail");`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I guess you press the <kbd>Enter</kbd> key for all input?

That <kbd>Enter</kbd> key will be added as a newline in the input buffer.

The `%[^\n]` format *stops* reading once it find a newline. And the first character it reads *is* a newline. So it doesn't read anything, and the array `p` will remain uninitialized with *indeterminate* contents.

You need to tell `scanf` to skip the leading newline, which is done by adding an explicit space in the format string:

```
scanf(" %99[^\n]",p);
//     ^
// Note space here
```

Note that I limit the input to 99 characters, which will not overflow the buffer. And also note that you don't need to read the newline after the string.

Comment: tell scanf to skip the leading newline --> tell scanf to skip the leading newline _and all other white-space_

Comment: `scanf(" %[^\n]",p);` sadly is worse than [`gets()`](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1694036/2410359) and deserves the same demise.

Comment: @chux-ReinstateMonica can you tell me why my Vs Code accepts gets() but online coding platforms do not?

Comment: Aniket Mani, `gets()`, since C11, is no longer part of the C standard library.  Your Vs compiler is either out-of-date, out-of-spec or using an extension.  The online coding platforms are adhering to C11 or later.  Consider never using `gets()`.